# how to I do svn switch on a second copy of a checkout

Tags: svn

I have a subversion checkout and I have about 30 switches from different folders in the checkout to branches. I want to do the same on another computer, but I dont want to manually create all the switches again. Is there a way to export the switches from my current checkout and import them into a separate checkout ?

Comment: You have about 30 svn switches? That doesn't make a ton of sense. Maybe I'm not correctly interpreting what you're trying to ask... So you have a checkout folder with a bunch of sub-directories I presume, correct? And in this checkout folder, you did an svn switch on all of the sub-directories?

Comment: yes, we have a project that has 200 folders and people work on each folder individually, therefore they can create a branch for each folder. In this case, I have 30 switches to 30 branches and I want to recreate this on another computer and not go thru the pain of doing the 30 switches again.

Comment: i meant to say sub-folders instead of folder. I checkout  folder with 200 sub-folders and the switches are done in the sub-folders.

Answer (score 1):

Ah.. Okay, I understand now. Thank you for clarifying. You actually have yourself in a bit of a pickle using the method you're currently using.

Here is the problem that you have. You have a root checkout folder with a bunch of "sub-projects" so to speak. My organization actually uses a structure similar to this. The method *you all* are using right now however, unfortunately requires you to do either one of two options:

1. The method you're using currently, checking out the root directory
   which then checks out all of the sub-projects.
2. Check out all of the sub-projects **you** need individually (which
   takes a long time).

The problem with this method is the issue you're asking about currently. In order to do this again, you have to go through the tiresome process of checking everything out and switching again.

However, there is a much, *much* easier solution to your issue. And that's using the svn:externals property. Inside of your `root` directory, you can make another folder called `MyProject` for example. For this folder `MyProject`, you can add a list of svn:externals (Paths to those 30 sub-folders of yours) and set them as properties **on** the `MyProject` folder. Now, whenever you checkout `MyProject` (regardless of what computer you're on) it will checkout that folder with that set of properties (i.e. One `svn checkout` call that additionally checks out all of your sub-projects without having to do 30 different svn switches). Now, every time you make a new branch of those initial sub-projects, instead of doing `svn switch` on every directory, all you have to do is update the list of properties on the `MyProject` folder to point to the branch of your choosing.

Comment: oh, i see. These are the symbolic links in the repository, correct ? I created those svn:externals before. Thanks !

Comment: Correct, they're very similar to Unix sym-links if you want to use that comparison. There are multiple advantages to using them. 1) Like I mentioned, you don't have to checkout 200 separate modules and you're only using a small subset of them. 2) Each developer on your team can have their own checkout folder, and even if you're sharing modules, you're still working on one unique location. 3) The "sym-links" are stored **in** the repository so you don't have to worry about transferring from machine to machine.